# Connect to database oracle using token msal

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, node-oracledb, passport-azure-ad

I am developing a backend in node with express, passport-azure-ad and oracledb, using this library to connect to Oracle, in the front end I use angular with the msal library to authenticate and obtain a token, is there any way to connect to a Oracle XE/Enteprise database with this same token?

I need to maintain data traceability with registered users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use that token to authenticate.  However once you have connected, you can set one or more of the 'end-to-end' tracing attributes shown in the node-oracledb doc [End-to-end Tracing, Mid-tier Authentication, and Auditing](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#endtoend) to maintain data traceability, for example:

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "mygenericuser",
    password      : mypw,
    connectString : "localhost/orclpdb1"
  }
);

connection.clientId = "myactualname";  // This gets recorded in audit trails etc
```

The old article [PHP Web Auditing, Authorization and Monitoring with Oracle Database](https://developer.oracle.com/dsl/php-web-auditing.html) may also be useful background.

Comment: you are a genius, it has helped me a lot, I did not read that section of the documentation
thank you